# How to integrate synthetic creatures with weaponry?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction

The question is based off of Striders from the Half Life series.  If you desire to answer the question, this site contains more information about Striders:  http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Strider

Here are the important parts about Striders:

Striders are gigantic lumbering synthetic creatures with three legs, and an extremely hard caparapce.  They are able to withstand grenades, rockets, etcetera, in fact.  They are Docile in the 'world' I'm building, unless aggravated, and can be turned into synthetic beasts with weaponry.  How does one tame these lumbering creatures, how do you weaponized them?
*Their purpose is a tank that absorbs damage, and destroys the enemy with heavy fire power.
*They are slow, and powerful
*They have two weapons on their underbelly, a cannon that fires beams of concentrated plasma, and a machine gun that fires a similar projectiles in bursts.

Ignore the above if you're already educated on Striders- How do you integrate synthetic weaponry into their carapace?  I want to know how you can grow the Strider cannons onto their underbellies, and how you can get these enormous three legged beasts to cooperate?  Do you modify their genetic code, do you surgically implant them, what?  What is the easiest and most effective way to turn Striders into killing machines that have been weaponized?
Edit:  And is it realistic?  Would it be possible?  Are synthetic weaponized creatures realistic in this regard?

Comment: You should include all necessary information in your post, as links may go out of date. Please edit your answer to provide a small excerpt from the linked site to give us all the needed information. Maybe mark it with a horizontal line to indicate the rest of the question for those who are familiar with the Strider.

Comment: Please do not post questions that are not answerable without visiting external sites.

Comment: This can be answered without viewing external sites, the external site just helps massively; Actually, might not even be a massive difference, but rather it just makes more sense this way.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?  It meets the sites criteria, it helps kids looking up stuff with their homework, it spikes interest, it's answerable, it isn't broad etc.

Comment: Questions get downvoted because they are unclear, display a lack of research, are unhelpful, or someone simply doesn't like the question. (Note: I did not vote on this question.)

Comment: Voting to close because I can count ten separate and distinct questions. Please refrain from asking multiple questions per question, especially if they diverge in their goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a "synthetic creature" is essentially a machine, yes, you can integrate anything you wish into it, as long as it's within the original design parameters.

I think the mistake you're making is that you're thinking of these things primarily as live creatures - who said they are?

Science is currently able to create "artificial" muscle tissue, and have it contract by applying the appropriate electric current to it. Assuming more advanced technology is available, you might build a sort of mechanical skeleton, with a computerized brain, weapon systems, etc, yet with muscles moving the creature instead of motors.

Comment: We know they're living creatures because they have active brains that control their nervous systems/etcetera.